# Pandas - Concat rows based on group of values in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a dataframe like this (summarized version), with 14 cols:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[01/10/2020,02/10/2020], 'Ticker': [AAPL,APPL], 
                   'Transaction':[Dividend,Tax], 'Value':[10,1]})
```

Table Format:

| Date | Ticker | Transaction | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/10/2020 | AAPL | Dividend | 10 |
| 01/10/2020 | AAPL | Tax | 1 |

I want to be able to append the tax row with the Dividend row, so long as the Date and the Ticker are exactly the same. The reason is that I want to end up with one row that contains Dividend = 10, Tax = 1, Net = 9.

I tried separating into two dataframes then concat by double index, but didn't quite get the result I wanted.

I tend to use Alteryx, so in Alteryx I'd join on unique keys of date and ticker, then drop the duplicated columns, then rename the cols with the same name.

Suggestions?

Expected Output:

| Date | Ticker | Transaction | Value Dividend | Value Tax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/10/2020 | AAPL | Dividend and Tax | 10 | 1 |

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), as well as expected output.

Comment: You only need to concatenate the transaction of the second row with the first row if other columns are the same, right?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for `pivot_table()`:

```
pd.pivot_table(
    df,
    index = ['Date', 'Ticker'],
    values = 'Value',
    columns = 'Transaction'
)
```